# Programmatically create identical ImageViews that can be controlled independently

Tags: java, android, imageview, game-physics

I am creating an app where bubbles bounce around the screen, you get points for popping them, and then they re-spawn.

Each bubble is exactly identical except for the speed and direction integers used to control their motion around the screen.

As of now I have a single ImageView called "bubble". Then I run the method randoms() which I created.

Code for `randoms()`:

```
    public void randoms(){

        ySpeedRand = new Random();
        xSpeedRand = new Random();
        yPolarityRand = new Random();
        xPolarityRand = new Random();

        ySpeed = ySpeedRand.nextInt(5) + 4;
        xSpeed = xSpeedRand.nextInt(5) + 4;
        yPolarity = yPolarityRand.nextInt(3) + 1;
        xPolarity = xPolarityRand.nextInt(3) + 1;

        if (xPolarity == 1){
            xSpeed*=-1;
        }
        if (yPolarity == 2){
            ySpeed*=-1;
        }

    }
```

Then I have a listener to check when the bubble is tapped and then I make it invisible, rerun the randoms() block, and then make it visible.

This is the handler that controls the position of the bubbles:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            bubble.setX(bubble.getX()+xSpeed);
            bubble.setY(bubble.getY()+ySpeed);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5);

        }
    };handler.post(run);
```

And I use this code to check if the bubble is still on the screen:

```
        final Handler checkHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable check = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (bubble.getX()>SCREEN_WIDTH-bubble.getWidth()/2){xSpeed*=-1;}
                if (bubble.getX()<0){xSpeed*=-1;}
                if (bubble.getY()>SCREEN_HEIGHT-bubble.getHeight()){ySpeed*=-1;}
                if (bubble.getY()<bubble.getHeight()/2+barHeight+actionBorder.getHeight()){ySpeed*=-1;}

                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);

            }
        };checkHandler.post(check);
```

Is there an easy way to simply expand this system so I can call a method createbubble() and then have the new bubbles assume the exact properties as the old ones, but with newly generated randoms?

I am 100% stuck and I cant find anything. Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was a little bit confused reading your question. Not sure why you're trying to use `ImageView`. Going with this as your goal:

- Create a game which spawns bubbles which can be popped
- When popped, bubbles should be moved to a random space on the screen
- When bubbles move off the screen, reverse their direction.

I would make the following classes at least:

- **Launcher**, where your main() method is stored and your game loop run
- **Window**, which `extends Canvas` and wherein you'll setup a `JFrame`
- **Control**, where physics are calculated every time Launcher completes a loop
- **Entity**, an abstract java object
- **Bubble**

Here's one way to make a game loop: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0

Here's an example of how to make a JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{
    public Window(Launcher launcher){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
        frame.setSize(700,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(launcher);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        launcher.setFrame(frame);
    }
}
```

To keep track of the bubbles, I would declare and initialize a `LinkedList<>` in the Control class. To create bubbles run something like this in Control:

```
public class Control{
    public LinkedList<Entity> entity = new LinkedList<Entity>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    public Control(){
        //You will have to define these constants in the Launcher class
        entity.add(
            rand.nextInt(Launcher.WINDOW_WIDTH),
            rand.nextInt(Launcher.WINDOW_HEIGHT)
        );
    }

    //Called every time Launcher completes a game loop
    tick(){
        for(int i=0; i<entity.size(); i++){
            entity.get(i).tick();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Entity class:

```
public abstract class Entity{
    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    public Entity(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public abstract void tick();
    public abstract void render(Graphics g);
    //Getters and setters here ...
}
```

In the Bubble class:

```
public class Bubble extends Entity{
    public double x = 0;
    public double y = 0;

    public Bubble(int x, int y){
        super(x,y);
    }

    public void tick(){
        //Physics go here
    }
    public void render(){
        //Graphics functions go here
    }
}
```

If any of this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll explain in more detail and even go as far as to make the entire program for you considering the simplicity of the task.